# Change Docker Volume storage location

Tags: backup, docker, storage, disk-volume

Since nearly the beginning, I have used mount binds for persistent data with docker, as the [official](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) way of backing up a docker volume is to give it to another container to save it in a tar...
Just using rsync on the directory mount seemed much better, but in basically every docker-compose example, volumes are used.

The Documentation states multiple reasons why volumes are so much better, and that you should only [use mount binds for configs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/#good-use-cases-for-bind-mounts) and so on.
As the performance is allegedly also better, I wanted to give it another try, but ran in to the unexpected issue that I can't change where Volumes are stored.

'/var/lib/docker/volumes' may be fine for most users, but I have a separate raid mounted under /mnt for actual data.

How do I define where docker stores volumes?

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49920624) is not really clear, as it seems like a complicated bind mount???

I've also found [this volume plugin](https://github.com/MatchbookLab/local-persist), but I can't believe that docker can't do that on its own.

You can even [move the docker root directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69751178), but I am unsure of the implications that this would have, so if anyone has further information on this, let me know.

If the answer is easy, hit me with a hammer and tell me how to do it, because I can't figure it out...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only option is to use the local-persist as you already mentioned or use the bind-mount.